# Google authentication not returning user name for some users

Tags: codeigniter

Google authentication isn't returning a username for users who don't have 
a Google+ account in codeigniter. This is my google config file; here i am giving all app details:

```
$config['google']['client_id']        = 'xxxxxxx';
$config['google']['client_secret']    = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$config['google']['redirect_uri']     = 'xxxxxxx';
$config['google']['application_name'] = 'Login to xxxxx';
$config['google']['api_key']          = '';
$config['google']['scopes']           = array('email');
```

This is my healper.in helper. I am calling the API like this:

```
$CI->config->load('google');
require APPPATH .'third_party/google-api-client/Google_Client.php';
require APPPATH .'third_party/google-api- 
client/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
$this->client = new Google_Client();
$this->client->setApplicationName($CI->config->item('application_name', 'google'));
$this->client->setClientId($CI->config->item('client_id', 'google'));
$this->client->setClientSecret($CI->config->item('client_secret', 'google'));
$this->client->setRedirectUri($CI->config->item('redirect_uri', 'google'));
$this->client->setDeveloperKey($CI->config->item('api_key', 'google'));
$this->client->setScopes($CI->config->item('scopes', 'google'));
$this->client->setAccessType('online');
$this->client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
$this->oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($this->client);
}
public function loginURL() {
return $this->client->createAuthUrl();
}
public function getAuthenticate() {
return $this->client->authenticate();
}
public function getAccessToken() {
return $this->client->getAccessToken();
}
public function setAccessToken() {
return $this->client->setAccessToken();
}
public function revokeToken() {
return $this->client->revokeToken();
}
public function getUserInfo() {
return $this->oauth2->userinfo->get();
}
```

This is my controller:

```
$auth = $this->google->getAuthenticate();
```

Here is how I'm getting the access token:

```
$gpInfo = $this->google->getUserInfo();
print_r($gpInfo);exit;
```

Yesterday I was getting this:

```
Array ( [id] => 105270387701232345676 [email] => myemail@gmail.com 
[verified_email] => 1 [name] => [given_name] => [family_name] => [picture] 
=> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/- 
XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg )
```

Any advice you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Be careful posting real e-mail addresses in your code body in the future; you don't know who could be monitoring new posts for such content.

Comment: can you tell me why i am not getting user name for someuser

Comment: Doesn't `oauth2->userinfo->get();` extend `Oauth2Request<Userinfoplus>`? I believe the type Userinfoplus is only going to contain information pulled from a user's Google+ profile: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/oauth2/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/oauth2/model/Userinfoplus.html

Comment: how can i get user info

Comment: please tell me any other option

Comment: can we get google gmail info not google plus